# Query on fetched activerecord data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to know that is it possible to make a query on fetched data from a model, without creating a database query.

Let there be a User model having type A and B

```
@users = User.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day)
type_a = @users.where(:type => A).limit(100)
type_b = @users.where(:type => B).limit(10)
```

Currently, it is executing 2 queries. But I want to run a single query to fetch data, and then extract type_a and type_b from it.
Is there any other method to do that.

Comment: Yes, there is, you can convert your relation to `Array`, using `to_a` and call `select`, but honestly I don't think you need this. Two DB queries are more efficient and perfectly fine in regard to clean code.

Comment: Yeah, what you're asking for help with makes your code worse imo. The above is relatively neat and expressive

Comment: @Sumit Sharma : are you going to use `@users` object in your template or else?

Comment: make @users.to_a and you can use select object for to retrieve data as you like.

Comment: There's even no need to do `to_a`, as Vijay Atmin stated, because `ActiveRecord::Relation#select` falls back to `Enumerable#select` if the block is provided. But still, you don't need this, don't do this.

Comment: I know that i can use the select method to do that. But i was curious to know, whether there is any other better method to do this. Anyway Thanks everyone.

Comment: The results from extracting A and B from a single query would not be the same as `User.where(type: [A,B])` would not return the records in the same order as  `@users.where(type: A)` when used with a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Possible by select method

```
@users = User.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day)
type_a = @users.select {|u| u.type == 'A'}.first(100)
type_b = @users.select {|u| u.type == 'B'}.first(10)
```

Comment: It will be of no use if the @users is large enough. That is the reason i am not interested in doing this.

Comment: @SumitSharma that's exactly why you should stick to two DB queries. :)